# bash script is skipping to create file in a loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am running a program in a bash script which takes around 1 sec to complete. The program instances are executed in a for loop with .5 sec pause and 100 times. However, I do not get 100 log files created in my directory as it is expected. I understand shell script is a sequential processing language, then why only 60 files are created generally in my case? Does shell script miss/skip creating files in a loop if it takes more time? Or it simply skips the cmd execution in that very iteration?

```
#!/bin/bash

IP="192.168.1.12"

for i in {1..100}                     
do
  echo "Instance..." "$i"
  filename=$(date +%H-%M-%S).log
  /usr/local/bin/myprog  "$IP"  36422  >  $filename 2>&1  &        # this prog takes 1 sec to complete
  sleep .5
done
```

to narrow down the issue, even if I removed the loop pause and replaced my program with touch cmd. Same issue. it does not create 100 files.

```
#!/bin/bash

IP="192.168.1.12"

for i in {1..100}                     
do
  echo "Instance..." "$i"
  filename=$(date +%H-%M-%S).log
  touch  $filename 2>&1  &    
done
```

Comment: You're overwriting the log files since you sleep only 0.5 seconds. Try with `filename=$(date +%H-%M-%S.%N).log` and you'll see.

Comment: `printf -v filename "%(%H-%M-%S.$EPOCHREALTIME)T%s" -1` maybe...

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you are introducing unnecessary noise to the problem.

Using H:M:S is going to repeat eventually. It's either not enough info, or too much. Personally, I'd either add the date, or use the epoch, *if you need the date*, but just from this simple example it doesn't look like you do.

Simplest case, just use the instance. No overwrites.
If you are only adding the wait to let the job work and not overwhelm the system, just don't bother to put it into background.

```
for log in {1..100}.log
do echo "Instance ${log%.log}"
   /usr/local/bin/myprog "$IP" 36422 > $log 2>&1 
done
```

If you *want* them to batch up a bit, maybe try `parallel`, or just cluster them a few at a time.

```
grp=8 # how many to run at a time
for i in {1..100}
do (( i%grp )) || wait
   echo "Instance $i"
   nice /usr/local/bin/myprog "$IP" 36422 > $i.log 2>&1 &
done
```

If you really do need timestamping and `sleep`s, You can still just add the loop counter to differentiate files with the same timestamp. Modifying your simplified loop:

```
for i in {1..100}                     
do echo "Instance..." "$i"
   filename=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).$i.log
   touch $filename 
done
```

Most of the time here is the `date` subshell. This loop on my laptop -

```
real    0m27.866s
user    0m1.451s
sys     0m21.945s
```

Just using the loop counter:

```
for i in {1..100}                     
do echo "Instance..." "$i"
   filename=$i.log
   touch $filename 
done
```

was

```
real    0m12.666s
user    0m0.741s
sys     0m10.293s
```

Taking out the call to `touch` -

```
for i in {1..100}
do echo "Instance..." "$i"
   filename=$i.log
   > $filename
done
```

took

```
real    0m0.076s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.078s
```

Spawning them ALL in bg (with no particular care) took each from a third to a half a second to run, but all hundred finished in about 10s.

```
time { 
for i in {1..100}
do echo "Instance..." "$i"; 
   time { filename=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).$i.log; touch $filename; } 2> $i.log 1>&2 &
done && wait; }
```

total:

```
real    0m10.079s
user    0m1.947s
sys     0m25.860s
```

I don't know whether fast really matter to you on this, but it never hurts to practice for the bigger jobs.